# HTML Agility Pack - How can append element at the top of Head element?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use HTML Agility Pack to append a script element into the top of the HEAD section of my html. The examples I have seen so far just use the `AppendChild(element)` method to accomplish this. I need the script that I am appending to the head section to come before some other scripts. How can I specify this?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.Load(filePath);
HtmlNode head = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head");
HtmlNode stateScript = htmlDocument.CreateElement("script");
head.AppendChild(stateScript);
stateScript.SetAttributeValue("id", "applicationState");
stateScript.InnerHtml = "'{\"uid\":\"testUser\"}'";
```

I would like a script tag to be added toward the top of HEAD rather than appended at the end.

Comment: Sidenote to others finding this question: `stateScript.InnerHtml=...` will sometimes do weird stuff to your javascript. To work around this you can instead do `stateScript.AppendChild(htmlDocument.CreateTextNode(scriptText));`

Answer (score 20):

Realizing that this is an old question, there is also the possibility of prepending child elements that might not have existed then.

```
// Load content as new Html document
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(oldContent);

// Wrapper acts as a root element
string newContent = "<div>" + someHtml + "</div>";

// Create new node from newcontent
HtmlNode newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(newContent);

// Get body node
HtmlNode body = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

// Add new node as first child of body
body.PrependChild(newNode);

// Get contents with new node
string contents = html.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 7):

Got it..

HtmlNode has the following methods:

```
HtmlNode.InsertBefore(node, refNode)
HtmlNode.InsertAfter(nodeToAdd, refNode)
```

Comment: Be careful when modifying HTML source. It can change other parts of the HTML code that maybe you don't want to touch `:/`